# Select which x-axis labels to show for lineplot with thousands of entries

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a lineplot with a few thousands entries for multiple series as is shown in the image:

[image: Large Lineplot with x-axis values]

I'd like to have the ability to select which values are shown on the x-axis, since this is currently random according to formatting choices.
In this plot, it shows "4,188,372,556,...", increasing the font size yields "4,212,420,628,836,..."

As one can imagine, when looking at Byte-Values, it would be more natural to display powers of 2 for example or something like "4,256,512,768,1024,...", so in steps of 256 Bytes.

Is there a way to influence which x-axis labels are shown? Or is there some trick to achieve this effect, given a few thousand entries, to specify to Excel which of those should get a label on the axis on a lineplot?

Comment: I think you may add a series for scatter line with markers to chart, the X values are the label value you need to shown on the X axis, and the Y values are 0. Then delete the original X axis label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an acceptable solution to my problem, which is highlighted in this picture:

[Altering the interval unit lets one select which labels to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ipub.png)

One can alter the interval between labels by specifying an interval unit. This way, it is independent of scheduling and also lets me represent my chart labels in a more sensible way.
This way, with 2048 data values, I can just take ever 256th value and hence have the labels [0,1024,2048,3072,4096,...], which is way more readable when considering Byte-values.